# Using RxJava Subject for Callback Wrapper

Tags: java, callback, rx-java

I am using a third party library that I am trying to encapsulate using RxJava so that I can expose the third party library's functionality to my application code via RxJava utilities.

After a third party library instance is obtained, it needs a callback set on it so that when a call is made to the library and it completes whatever it needs to do, it can call back to the set callback `Object` to notify the application that it has completed whatever it was doing.

I thought that this would be a good use for a `Subject`, but I can not quite sure that this is the correct way to implement it. When the `Wrapper` class's `doFirstThing` method is called, the `Wrapper` class calls the `Subject`'s `doOnSubscribe` method and sets a new `Action0` `Object` that when called, makes the appropriate method call to the third party library.

When the third party library has completed whatever it was doing, it calls the appropriate method on the callback `Object` the `Wrapper` class set on it. In the set callback's method, the `Wrapper` calls the `Subject`'s `onNext` method with the value that was passed to the callback method.

Is this the correct way to implement this type of functionality?

```
public class Wrapper {

    private final ThirdPartyLibrary mThirdPartyLibrary;
    private final Subject<Boolean, Boolean> mCallbackSubject;

    public Wrapper() {
        mThirdPartyLibrary = ThirdPartyLibrary.getInstance();
        mThirdPartyLibrary.setCallback(new WrapperThirdPartyCallback())

        mCallbackSubject = new SerializedSubject<>(PublishSubject.<Boolean>create());
    }

    @Override
    public Observable<Boolean> doFirstThing() {
        return mConfigureSubject.doOnSubscribe(new Action0() {
            @Override
            public void call() {
                mThirdPartyLibrary.doFirstThing();
            }
        });
    }

    public class WrapperThirdPartyCallback implements ThirdPartyCallback {
        @Override
        public void doOneThingComplete(boolean success) {
            mCallbackSubject.onNext(success);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It will be better to ask such kind of questions in http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ . StackOVerflow is intended for problems, not reviews.

Comment: Essentially what the problem is, as @akarnokd stated, is the `doOnSubscribe` method call to "kick-off" the flow.

Answer (score 0):

Using a `Subject` here is appropriate. However, I'm not sure about the use of `doOnSubscribe` because it will call `doFirstThing` as many times as there are subscribers which may run concurrently and may receive multiple success notifications.

Comment: That is the behavior that I am seeing. I actually got into a situation where there was another method `doSecondThing` that called the `doOnSubscribe` as well and it got into an infinite loop as calling one method would call the other.